# Any smartform control that lets me select Page Layouts?

Tags: ektron

In the smart form controls, my choices are link selector and resource selector. The link will only allow me to enter one by hand or select from the library. The resource selector only allows me to select content blocks, but page layout pages are not listed.

Is there any smart form control that will let me select a page layout page?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You could make the page layout a template and then make it the template for the smart form. The other option is reverse the link, and use a resource selector on the page layout to link to the smart form (assuming that your relationships are 1 to 1).

Answer (score 0):

Bill Cava came up with the answer over at Ektron. There is a filter in the render that needs to be modified.

http://developer.ektron.com/Forums/?v=t&t=880